# Check any level of parent nodes with XPath and XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have searched, but might have missed something obvious just because I don't know what to search for. And I found it hard to explain my question as a simple question, so let me explain: I am using the following code (XSLT 1.0 & XPath) to check if the parent to this node belongs to the last grand-parent node or not:

```
<xsl:when test="count(parent::*/preceding-sibling::*)+1 = count(parent::*/parent::*/*)">
```

It works exactly like I want. What I would like though is to make it more general in one way or the other, to make it work with even more parent nodes. I can add another template match and add another test:

```
<xsl:when test ="count(parent::*/parent::*/preceding-sibling::*)+1 = count(parent::*/parent::*/*)">
```

Is there a way to add "parent::*/" in a recursive template loop instead of creating a lot of specific template matches? Or should I work out a better XPath code altogether?

Please note: I want to do a check for every level of parent nodes. Is the parent the last of the parents, is the grand-parent the last of the grand-parents, etc.

For clarity's sake, I use it like this:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="count(parent::*/preceding-sibling::*)+1 = count(parent::*/parent::*/*)">
    <!-- show image A -->
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <!-- show image B -->
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Use the ancestor:: axis instead of parent:: ?

Comment: @Mike I will look it up, at first glance it seems like it is what I want.

Comment: Hm, no it wasn't really what I was after, since I want to know for every individual ancestor if it's the last or not, not all of them together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<xsl:when test="count(parent::*/preceding-sibling::*)+1 = count(parent::*/parent::*/*)">
```

can be simplified to:

```
<xsl:when test="not(../following-sibling::*)">
```

In plain English *"my parent does not have a following element sibling"*.

---

That would be easily modifiable to:

```
<xsl:when test="not(../../following-sibling::*)">
```

In plain English *"my parent's parent does not have a following element sibling"*. Etc.

---

To check all ancestors at the same time:

```
<xsl:when test="not(ancestor::*/following-sibling::*)">
```

In plain English *"none of my ancestors has a following element sibling"*.

---

To check parent and grandparent at the same time:

```
<xsl:when test="not(ancestor::*[position() &lt;= 2]/following-sibling::*)">
```

In plain English *"none of my two closest ancestors has a following element sibling"*.

---

**EDIT** To check all ancestors individually, either use a recursive template (advantage: the position of the inner `<xsl:apply-templates>` determines if you effectively go up or down the list of ancestors):

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="line-img">
  <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
    <!-- show image A -->
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)">
    <!-- show image B -->
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:apply-templates select=".." mode="line-img" />
</xsl:template>

<!-- and later... -->

<xsl:apply-templates select=".." mode="line-img" />
```

...or a simple for-each loop (always works in document order):

```
<xsl:for-each select="ancestor::*">
  <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
    <!-- show image A -->
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)">
    <!-- show image B -->
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

...or, to be completely idiomatic (always works in document order):

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="line-img">
  <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
    <!-- show image A -->
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)">
    <!-- show image B -->
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- and later... -->

<xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*" mode="line-img" />
```

Comment: That first part makes a lot of sense and is really useful! I was a little bit unclear in my first post though, because I'd need an individual check for each of the ancestors.

Comment: I guess one of the other variants will do what you want?

Comment: Not really, if I understand you correctly. But using the "not(../following-sibling::*)" simplification together with a recursive template that sends the parent node as a parameter will probably do what I want, since I need the result of the test for every ancestor, like: "Yes, No, No, Yes, No" for example.

Comment: @timlarsson Ah, you need *every result* separately. Then yes, a recursive template is the way to go. (May I ask why?)

Comment: Exactly! Actually it's for drawing a folder structure, with subfolders and sub-subfolders etc. and I want to have a downward pointing line if the parent folder isn't the last, like in this following random [picture](http://blog.picbackman.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/folder-structure-11.jpg)

You see how the "marriage" folder doesn't have a line from the "New Year" folder. I'm doing such a thing with tiny images.

Comment: Yes, I suspected exactly this scenario. :) I've modified my answer, there are three approaches to this. I suggest you use the last approach.

Comment: That is almost exactly what I wanted! Since I insert the images from left to right, I have to check the ancestors in the reverse order (from root to child), so I guess moving the "apply-templates" tag before the "if" tags would reverse the result, right?

Comment: Exactly that is what would happen. :)

Comment: Perfect! :) I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough in the main post, but it's difficult to express yourself clearly when you're not a native English speaker, nor all too familiar with XPath and XSLT :) I would +1 if I could, but I'm not allowed to yet.

Comment: Never mind, that's all-right. Be aware that the last approach would do the right thing as well, see: http://www.xmlplayground.com/6051D2 (In other words, template application happens in document order, so does `<xsl:for-each>`, which you could also use. Only *indexing* into a reverse axis with XPath works in reverse, i.e. `[1]` is always closest to the context node.)

Comment: @timlarsson Of course, XSLT/XPath 2.0+ have [the `reverse()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-reverse) to reverse a sequence. The above answer is XSLT 1.0 compatible.

Comment: Yeah, there are many useful additions to 2.0, but I can only use 1.0 at the moment. I think this will work just perfectly, and will allow this little project to become more complete and user friendly. (No limitation on folder depth etc. since I won't need to hard code each subfolder).